# Proper way to use a Moose class attribute in a regex?

Tags: regex, perl, accessor, moose

I now know that the proper way to access `Moose` class attributes is to ALWAYS go through the accessor method that is automatically generated by `Moose`.

See [Friedo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572421/writing-to-read-only-attributes-inside-a-perl-moose-class/32572706#32572706) to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572421/writing-to-read-only-attributes-inside-a-perl-moose-class) for the reasons why.

However this raises a new question...  How do you ensure `Moose` class attributes are handled correctly within regular expressions?

---

**Take the following for example:**

*Person.pm*

```
package Person;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Moose;

has 'name' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Str');
has 'age'  => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Int');

# Make package immutable
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
```

*test.pl*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Person;

my $person = Person->new(
    name => 'Joe',
    age  => 23,
);

my $age = 23;

# Access age the "proper" way
if ($age =~ m/$person->age()/) {
    print "MATCH 1!\n";
}

# Access age the "improper" way
if ($age =~ m/$person->{age}/) {
    print "MATCH 2!\n";
}
```

**This code will output the following:**

```
MATCH 2!
```

---

It seems that Perl does not parse the accessor method correctly when it is placed in a regex...  What is the proper way to handle this?

I know I could just do this:

```
my $compare_age = $person->age();
if ($age =~ m/$compare_age/) {
    # MATCH!
}
```

But how can I get it to work without the extra step of storing it in a separate variable, while still going through the accessor?

Comment: I realize this is a contrived example, but generally you shouldn't be using a regex for integers anyway. Can you explain what you're actually using the regex for?

Comment: I have objects that store CVS file information and I'm using regex's to compare file data.  I came up with a generic problem to express the problem as simply as possible. (The attribute could really be any arbitrary string, not necessarily an integer).

Comment: For example I may want to see if a string contains a file name so I would use something like this: `if ($string =~ m/$file->name()/) { }`

Comment: See [How do I expand function calls in a string?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-expand-function-calls-in-a-string?) in perlfaq4 (the contents of `m//` are interpolated similar to `qq`). Personally, I find using an intermediate variable to be more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `/$compare_age/` is wrong since `23 =~ /2/` matches. Fixed:

```
$age =~ /^\Q$compare_age\E\z/
```

There is a trick to evaluate an arbitrary expression within double-quote string literals and regex literals.

```
$age =~ /^\Q${\( $person->age() )}\E\z/
```

Buy what you should be using is the following:

```
$age == $person->{age}
```

Comment: I know matching an integer is a stupid example, but that's not the point.  The point is to be able to go through the accessor for the attribute in the regex which would mean using `$person->age()` instead of `$person->{age}` and getting it to be recognized correctly as a regex.

Comment: That was answered, but you asked what was proper. And that's not proper.

Comment: Thats so syntactically ugly... lol, is there really no better way?  Also for the sake of example I don't care if 23 =~ /2/ comes out to a match.  I just want the simplest possible syntax to make the regex work at all.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 The simplest possible syntax is to use a temporary variable.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, what about a situation where I want a regex to match multiple attributes at once and would need to define many temporary variables.  That just seems bulky and unneccessary.

Comment: That makes no sense. You can only perform a regex match against one value.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 you would need to build a pattern like `/foo|bar|baz/` to match against several attributes at the same time.

Comment: @simbabque, That isn't what I meant by multiple at once.  I meant I have a regular expression that contains multiple attributes within it. like `/$foo$bar$baz/` all in one regex

Comment: What would you match against?

Comment: Anything where a bunch of atomic values from the attributes form a value, like the name of a product that's made up of size, color, brand and model. But I'd make a custom method that returns it, or a lazy attribute with clearer and triggers on the parts. Then save that in a variable and build regex from that.

Comment: No, then you'd need a joining and an escaping mechanism, which means you'd have to canonize first, which makes a regex approach much longer than the alternative (parsing and comparing), seeing as canonizing requires parsing on the first place